# Values not getting selected into the dropdown when page is postback in older version of firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a jQuery function which execute when page is post back by using back button. But the dropdown value does not change when page is post back in the older version of Firefox. In older version it is just showing the default values when page is post back. Below is the jQuery function:

```
function loadData() {
    try {
        var URL = "/Home/LoadBackdata/" + new Date().getMilliseconds();
        $.post(URL, null, function (data) {
            debugger;
            if (data != "") {
                var backData = data.split(",");
                if (backData[0] != "") {
                    $('#ConsignorAddressCountryId option').removeAttr('selected');
                    // [1]
                    $("#ConsignorAddressCountryId option[value=" + backData[0] +").prop('selected', true);
                    //ConsigneeAddressCountryId is the id of another class which consist of a dropdown 
                    $('#ConsigneeAddressCountryId option').removeAttr('selected');
                    $("#ConsigneeAddressCountryId option[value=" + backData[3] +").prop('selected', true);
                    $('#drpQuantity option').removeAttr('selected');
                    $('#drpQuantity').prop('selectedIndex', ((parseInt(backData[13]) == 0) ? 0 : (parseInt(backData[13]) - 1)));
                }
            }
        });
```

`[1]` is where I am removing the default selected value - `ConsignorAddressCountryId` is the id of the class which consist of a dropdown.

I have also tried some things. Below is the code:

```
function loadData() {
    try {

        var URL = "/Home/LoadBackdata/" + new Date().getMilliseconds();
        $.post(URL, null, function (data) {
            debugger;
            if (data != "") {
                var backData = data.split(",");
                if (backData[0] != "") {
                    $('#ConsignorAddressCountryId option').removeAttr('selected');
                    $("#ConsignorAddressCountryId").find('option:Selected').removeAttr("selected");
                    document.getElementById('ConsignorAddressCountryId').selectedIndex = -1;
                    var ttt = $("#ConsignorAddressCountryId option[value=" + backData[0] + "]").text();
                    $("#dvQuoteFrom >div >a >span >.selectBox-label").first().text("ttt");
                    $("#ConsignorAddressCountryId option[value=" + backData[0] + "]").prop('selected', true);
                    $('#ConsigneeAddressCountryId option').removeAttr('selected');
                    document.getElementById('ConsigneeAddressCountryId').selectedIndex = -1;
                    var Consignee = $("#ConsigneeAddressCountryId option[value=" + backData[0] + "]").text();
                    $("#dvQuoteTo >div >a >span >.selectBox-label").first().text(Consignee);
                    $("#ConsigneeAddressCountryId option[value=" + backData[3] + "]").prop('selected', true);
                    $("#drpQuantity").find('option:Selected').removeAttr("selected");
                    document.getElementById('drpQuantity').selectedIndex = -1;
                    var Quantity = $("#drpQuantity option[value=" + backData[13] + "]").text();
                    $("#divQuantity>a >span >.selectBox-label").first().text(parseInt(10));


                    $('#drpQuantity').prop('selectedIndex', ((parseInt(backData[13]) == 0) ? 0 : (parseInt(backData[13]) - 1)));

                }

            }
        });
```

But it still nor working in older versions of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use reset function like to remove selected :

```
$('#yourdropdownid').reset();
```

And to set selected value, you can user val() like :

```
$('#yourdropdownid').val(your value);
```

Comment: This is not working any other way through i can fix for older version of firefox.